# flink webui logs failed and jobmanager always shutdown on kubernetes

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, apache-flink

deployed a flink with Standalone Kubernetes Application Cluster(Deployment Modes is Application),

flink version is 1.14.4, and run in kubernetes, standalone-applicationn mode

deploy steps and yaml use:
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/#application-mode

**problems:**

1. the flink is running in kubernetes, but the logs cannot view in the flink-webui, only through "kubectl logs" or "docker logs"
2. after a moment jobmanager restart then shutdown , not sure also the logger problem

about logger problem, search some solutions but cannot work in my case or just only see taskmanager stdout and no jonmanager logs or stdout; and jobmanager shutdown no idea now

**some logger error info from console:**

> ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '74a14482' at 'null' in 'null'
>
> UnknownTaskExecutorException: No TaskExecutor registered under 10.244.0.85:6122-cbd9ad.
>
> ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.taskmanager.TaskManagerStdoutFileHandler [] - Failed to transfer file from TaskExecutor 10.244.0.85:6122-b815fd.
> java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: The file STDOUT does not exist on the TaskExecutor.
>
> Thread-20 ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender
>
> ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@778d1062] unable to create manager for [] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@7a64d6ab[pattern=.%i, append=false, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=104857600)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=10, useMax=true), advertiseURI=null, layout=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]] java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@778d1062] unable to create manager for [] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@7a64d6ab[pattern=.%i, append=false, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=104857600)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=10, useMax=true), advertiseURI=null, layout=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]]
>
> globalEventExecutor-1-1 ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
> globalEventExecutor-1-1 ERROR Unable to locate appender "RollingFileAppender" for logger config "root"
> Thread-20 ERROR Unable to create file  java.io.IOException: No such file or directory, at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
>
> globalEventExecutor-1-1 ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender

**jobmanager shutdown log:**

> 2022-04-20 01:41:09,138 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM. Shutting down as requested.
> 2022-04-20 01:41:09,140 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Shutting StandaloneApplicationClusterEntryPoint down with application status UNKNOWN. Diagnostics Cluster entrypoint has been closed externally..
> 2022-04-20 01:41:09,142 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.MiniDispatcherRestEndpoint [] - Shutting down rest endpoint.
> 2022-04-20 01:41:09,146 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                     [] - Stopped BLOB server at 0.0.0.0:6124
> 2022-04-20 01:41:09,184 globalEventExecutor-1-1 ERROR Unable to locate appender "RollingFileAppender" for logger config "root"
> 2022-04-20 01:41:09,357 Thread-48 ERROR Unable to locate appender "RollingFileAppender" for logger config "root"
> 2022-04-20 01:41:09,397 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Shutting down remote daemon.
> 2022-04-20 01:41:09,397 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Shutting down remote daemon.
> 2022-04-20 01:41:09,404 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
> 2022-04-20 01:41:09,406 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
> 2022-04-20 01:41:09,453 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Remoting shut down.
> 2022-04-20 01:41:09,455 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Remoting shut down.

**thx all!!**

Comment: Did you create the `jobmanager-service.yaml` and the `flink-configuration-configmap.yaml`? I would start with the native Kis example https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/resource-providers/native_kubernetes/ to get acquainted and then go to the raw example.

Comment: have created the common cluster resource definitions first: flink-configuration-configmap.yaml, jobmanager-service.yaml, and jobmanager-rest-service.yaml,
then craeted jobmanager-job.yaml and taskmanager-job-deployment.yaml,
the cluster in kubernetes can run and execute the job,
but the two problem no ideas

Comment: cluster can execute job and sutask before shutdown, but run a little minutes jobmanager always shutdown then the pod quit, taskmanager no quit..

Comment: `No configuration found for` suggests that there is a missconfiguration. May e take a look at the `flink-configuration-configmap.yaml`. Even though it is correct, I think that the other pods are not reading it.

Comment: `No configuration found for` because I changed the docker-entrypoint.sh replace the official image one for the stdout loger, like `exec $(drop_privs_cmd) "$FLINK_HOME/bin/taskmanager.sh" start-foreground >$FLINK_HOME/log/STDOUT_tm.log 2>&1 "${args[@]}"`,  diff is added `>$FLINK_HOME/log/STDOUT_tm.log 2>&1 `, but it's also not work or the container run error..

Comment: btw, about the jobmanager always crashed and shutdown, from the log any idea?

Comment: `ERROR Unable to locate appender "RollingFileAppender" for logger config "root` is saying that you didnt configure log4j/logger properly. I think it wants to create a file to write logs but it cannot. That is part of the configuration that I said before.